# actionscript3 calling functions in Main from a another class

Tags: actionscript-3

Even I am programmer I am very, very, new to as3.
Problem:
I have define a classA in aA.sp file.

package{

```
     import flash.display.Sprite
     .......
     public class aA extends Sprite{
        function aA{ ....   }      //constructor

        functio playVideo(url){.....}
   }
```

I have defined Main in the document class in the cs4 .flv file
The Main class is defined in the Main.as file.
package{
          import flash.display.Sprite;
      ....

```
  public class Main extends Sprite{
    public function Main(){
         var v:Sprite = new aA();
        v.playVideo("clip.flv");
        addChild(v);
    }
}
```

}

When test on cs4 (contol>enter) I get following error

1061: Call to a possibly undefined method playVideo through a reference with static type flash.display:Sprite

Please help me. I am stuck! ( may be its a simple error ) Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make sure your spelling is ok. I noticed that "function" is missing the "n" for your playVideo method declaration. Also class names should start with an uppercase letter. The Class name and files name, should also match, so if you have the class named Foo, then you file will be called Foo.as

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your Main class is in the same package as the aA class  (or otherwise use import to import that package). Set the type for your v to aA ( `var v:aA = new aA();` ) .

Comment: An import won't change visibility.

Comment: Wonderful the change works like a charm! as you said created an instance and call the function: a big step for me and small..... Thank you so much.RWW

Answer (score 1):

Make playVideo public or make sure aA is in the same package as Main.

Comment: np, you should accept one of the answers (click the "check" symbol below the vote count) to mark this question as solved, and/or vote up the answers you like. ;)